Next.js favicon and images in the _document file do not appear in the build
I am having problems with images in the build of my Next.js application. In other files, I fixed this by importing images like this:
import Image from 'myPath'

<Image src={Image}>

instead of:
<Image src='mypath'>

But in _document.tsx, it does not work on build. The files are inside the public folder.
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href='/apple-icon.png' type="image/png" sizes="180x180" />
        <link rel="icon" href='/icon-32x32.png' type="image/png" sizes="32x32" />
        <link rel="icon" href='/icon-16x16.png' type="image/png" sizes="16x16" />

And when I try something like this and move the files to the assets folder:
import Image from 'myPath'
    
   
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href={Image.src} type="image/png" sizes="180x180" />

I'm getting this error:
./src/assets/apple-icon.png
Images cannot be imported within pages/_document.js. Please move image imports that need to be displayed on every page into pages/_app.js.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/custom-document-image-import
Location: src/pages/_document.tsx

